# Accessing iPod Touch data with Linux and ifuse

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch, ipod, data-recovery

I have an old iPod touch, model A1318, that has my music on it. My computer was stolen, and my Time Machine backup was encrypted with the password and the hint stored on the stolen computer, so this iPod is the only backup I have. I want to access the music files on it.

I searched online and found [ifuse](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse). I installed it and confirmed that it works. For example, I connect an iPhone 4 running iOS 9.3.6, see the device on the left bar, and run:

```
$ ifuse /path/to/some/existing/folder/
Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device.
Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device.
```

So I disconnect, reboot the device, reconnect. I see a pop-up on the computer asking that the device trust the computer, answer "Trust" on that pop-up on the device, run the same command, and then I am able to see the data and play a song file.

When I do the same procedure with the iPod connected, I see:

```
No device found, is it connected?
If it is make sure that your user has permissions to access the raw usb device.
If you're still having issues try unplugging the device and reconnecting it.
```

I tried disconnecting and reconnecting, as well as rebooting, and I got the same result. The image shows that the device is connected and shows on Files. But opening that location shows only the pictures under `DCIM`. I am running Ubuntu 23.04.

How can I fix this and access the data on the device?